# how to match "ABC-123" but not "XABC-123" in a regular expression

Tags: regex, solaris, grep

I have this egrep search:

```
egrep -is "(ABC-[0-9]+)"
```

which matches ABC-123 anywhere in a string.

I'd like it to ignore XABC-456 or YABC-789.

In other words, those examples should output "ok":

```
echo "ABC-123" | egrep -is "(ABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"
echo "test ABC-123" | egrep -is "(ABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"
```

But this shouldn't:

```
echo "XABC-123" | egrep -is "(<fill in>ABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"
```

I tried this without any luck (no output):

```
echo "ABC-123" | egrep -is "(\bABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"
```

(I'm running Solaris 10)

How can I do that?

Comment: I tried the last line, `echo "ABC-123" | egrep -is "(\bABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"`, on Cygwin, and it works as expected for me. It's *possible* you need to escape the backslash, but it should work as is. Here's my output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DuuwNyY9

Comment: It definitively doesn't work as expected on Solaris (tried to escape as well). It does on Linux, but I need it on Solaris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `\b` doesn't work for you, have you tried `((^| )ABC-[0-9]+)`?

Comment: Yes, it does work for the inputs I tried, but I'd rather like something that matches all word boundaries instead of just the one I can think of.

Comment: Yeah, but if `\b` doesn't work it's hard to work around that.  How about `(^|\s)ABC-[0-9]+` to at least match all whitespace?

Comment: Ok, it seems this is the best approach with egrep. Anyway, I finally did it with gnu grep, which seems to also be on this system ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It look like you're looking for `\bABC-[0-9]+` - [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Another option is to use a [negetive lookbedind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), whci gives you more control over what can and cannot be before the match: `(?<![a-z])ABC-[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do :

```
^(ABC-[0-9]+)
```

This way you're telling you want the line to start with your regexp.

Comment: I don't want it to start with my regexp ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
echo "XABC-123" | egrep -is "(\bABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"
```

There are a couple solutions that propose using ^ (starts with...) however, they will fail if you are looking at " ABC-123" which you might want to catch.  Word boundaries is probably what you want, unless you are looking for starts with...

Here's some sample output:

```
tim@Ikura ~
$ echo " ABC-123" | egrep -is "(\bABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"
 ABC-123
ok

tim@Ikura ~
$ echo "ABC-123" | egrep -is "(\bABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"
ABC-123
ok

tim@Ikura ~
$ echo "XABC-123" | egrep -is "(\bABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"

tim@Ikura ~
$
```

**Update:** Solaris issues...  "Searching for a word isn't quite as simple as it at first appears. The string "the" will match the word "other". You can put spaces before and after the letters and use this regular expression: " the ". However, this does not match words at the beginning or end of the line. And it does not match the case where there is a punctuation mark after the word.

There is an easy solution. The characters "\<" and ">" are similar to the "^" and "$" anchors, as they don't occupy a position of a character. They do "anchor" the expression between to only match if it is on a word boundary. The pattern to search for the word "the" would be "\<[tT]he>". The character before the "t" must be either a new line character, or anything except a letter, number, or underscore. The character after the "e" must also be a character other than a number, letter, or underscore or it could be the end of line character."

```
tim@Ikura ~
$ echo "XABC-123" | egrep -is "(\<ABC-[0-9]+\>)" && echo "ok"

tim@Ikura ~
$ echo " ABC-123" | egrep -is "(\<ABC-[0-9]+\>)" && echo "ok"
 ABC-123
ok
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't output the expected result: echo "ABC-123" | egrep -is "(\bABC-[0-9]+)" && echo "ok"

Comment: Egrep doesn't normally use Perl-compatible regular expressions. Maybe `egrep -is '\<ABC-[0-9]+'` will give you joy.

Comment: @LHMathies: no luck either, but I'm not stuck to egrep if I can find anything better

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "XABC-123" | egrep -is "^ABC-[0-9]+" && echo "ok"
```

EDIT: To accept `ABC` when anything but a letter precedes it:

```
echo "XABC-123" | egrep -is "(^|[^A-Z])ABC-[0-9]+" && echo "ok"
```

Comment: I don't want it to only match at start

Comment: If you specify more exactly what you will accept immediately preceding your `ABC-123`, we can probably help you.

Comment: I'd accept everything that contains ABC-123 (but the occurence can't be anything else like XABC-123)

Comment: Edited to match any non-letter before the string -- building on @sverre's solution.